# Export Data to multiple Excel cells from one RichTextBox C#

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I am receiving data from a COM device into a RichTextBox.
More than one result is displayed under each other in the RichTextBox as I receive data.
I am able to export the data to Excel but it does not put every result in its own cell under each other. Instead it exports all the data from the RichTextBox into one cell.
Can you please point me in the right direction to accomplish my task?
Using WinForms C#
Please see attached images.

[InterFace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd5nH.png)

[Current Excel sheet being Created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lQsn.png)

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        if (xlApp == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!!");
            return;
        }


        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Date";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Batch No";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Totale Sakke";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Pallet Gewig";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Tipe Sak";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 6] = "Kultivar";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 7] = "Gewig p/sak";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1] = DateTime.Today;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2] = txtBatch.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 3] = txtTotaleSakke.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 4] = txtPalletWeight.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 5] = cmbTipeSak.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 6] = cmbKultivar.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 7] = txbWeightList.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Columns.AutoFit();
        xlWorkSheet.Rows.AutoFit();


        xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\Huiz\\Documents\\Lewering Excel\\csharp-Excel.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);

        MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file C:\\csharp-Excel.xls");
```

Comment: Is file CSV or XLSX..Probably CSV so open file in Notepad (or any text editor) and check what characters are used to separate the columns.

Comment: How do you create the Excel file? Post your code. Excel isn't a text format. `xlsx` is a ZIP package containing well-formed XML files. Did you save the data into a CSV file with a fake extension? You can create real XML files easily with libraries like EPPlus, ClosedXML, NPOI or even the low-level Open XML SDK

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Posted my code

Comment: Your code does what you told it to - put the multiline text inside `txbWeightList.Text` into the cell B8. What did you expect instead? That Excel would somehow generate "subcells" for each line? That's not possible. When you see "detail" rows in some Excel sheets it's actually N rows with all common cells merged vertically. Another possibility is to actually group Excel rows by specific columns.

Comment: What are you trying to produce? You can't produce something that Excel itself doesn't allow

Answer (score 0):

```
sting[] stringList= stringtxbWeightList.Text.Split(' ');
for (int row=2;row<(stringList.Length+2);row++)
{
xlWorkSheet.Cells[row, 7]=stringList[row-2];


}
```

Comment: What is `stringtxbWeightList`?

Comment: Thank you the above code solved my problem!!